# Sublime like Multiple Cursors in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, browser, text-cursor

Do you have an idea how to get the Sublime or Cloud 9 like Multiple Cursors functionality to the browser?

I want multiple cursors in a `textarea`, maybe in multiple text areas. Should be possible with HTML5, but didn't find anything in the web!

Thank you!

Comment: dunno if this does it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592627/using-multiple-carets-in-single-or-multiple-textareas-and-textboxes

Comment: that stackoverflow link mentions http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=about  which is open source and written in javascript, so the "secret" should be there!

Answer (score 6):

As barlop said **ace editor** has multiple cursors, if you want to take a look to its magic you could maybe take a look to [multi_select.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/ffbb6b25231bcc2cea49cc2788b93e32498efde7/src/multi_select.js) at aces github repo.

In order to give you a little idea on how to do it, there's no `textarea` except under the *main cursor*. Ace breaks down text into multiple `divs` with the appeareance of a big `textarea`. When you place multiple cursors, ace copies the text entered in the *main cursor* to the other `spans` or `divs`.