# Using multiple carets in single or multiple textareas and textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

#### I think I may already know the answer to this one but...

Is it possible to have two carets in a single textbox, or have two separate textboxes focused at the same time allowing the user to type into both symataniously?

I know you can simulate this by adding a keydown listener and making their values match, but I want the visible caret in both fields.

If not, does anyone have any ideas on how to simulate this?

Comment: How to simulate the caret or how to simulate anything else?

Comment: `"... two carets in a single textbox ..."` why on earth you woud need two carets within a textbox?

Comment: This is one of the best features of `Sublime Text 2`, I would love to do this in Javascript, but never found a solution.. This would be a  really handy tool..

Comment: What @JustAnil said...

Comment: @lededje Till you find a proper solution, you can use [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy8DP/1/). It hasn't any visusal effects, but the cursor position and selection is preserved, when toggling between two textareas. The snippet works fine in FF22, IE10 and Opera12, but not well in Chrome27.

Comment: No, you can't have two carets or elements focused at the same time. You can create your own carets though, which is what these Web apps are doing. Here's an example of how to create a terminal-style caret: http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html, and you could make it blink with a CSS animation.

Comment: take a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/27946441/4453971][1] if it could help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27946441/4453971

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ace editor supports multiple cursors/carets like Sublime Text:

http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd(⌘)</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on OS X) in the live demo on that page to get multiple cursors and type away!

You can also select a bunch of code and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent a tab space, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to outdent a tab space.

Comment: Excellent plugin! Looks like it does exactly what the asker wants.

Comment: This is an impressive plugin, and I have forked it, but it isn't quite what I wanted. This comes with the weight of being a code editor, where as all I wanted was a text area or input box. I'll mark this answer as correct if no one comes up with anything better, as I think it will help most other viewers of this question.

Comment: @lededje looks like it's open source so you may be able to find out how it does it?

Comment: @barlop I've spent a few hours looking at the code I'm still no closer to finding the answer. I don't have the time to look any further.

Answer (score 2):

Check out @Sly_cardinal answer, That does everything you require, it is more off a "heavy" solution, but is certainly the only way you'll get something like this. It can be customized with a bit of work but its definitely the correct answer.

+1 @Sly_cardinal - Just what i've been looking for!

---

Rendering a text area is handled by the user agent (browser), we can control the style, look and feel, but unfortunately not the functionality *(To be able to do multiple cursors anyway)*.

Bummer.. This would be **amazing!**

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<html>
<body>
    <input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress()" onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()"><br>
    <span id="lblValue">The text box contains: </span>
        <input id="secvalue" type="text">
</body>

<script>
    function edValueKeyPress()
    {
        var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
        var s = edValue.value;

        var lblValue = document.getElementById("secvalue");
        lblValue.value = s;


    }
</script>    

</html>
```

I suppose this is your requirement

Comment: does not work.. http://jsfiddle.net/jyXJr/ This isn't what the OP was asking, he wants `multiple cursors` inside the same text area.