# JavaScript Background Text Selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contenteditable container and I would like to accomplish a similar effect that Google Docs has when you insert a link - via typing in a panel and keep the original text selected:

**desired effect(Google Docs)**
[image: desired effect]

However, I don't seem to be able to keep the selection while focusing on the new panel without changing the background ie whenever I focus on the new input, the original text in the contenteditable loses focus(the cursor in the contenteditable is not the real one):

**current state(my contenteditable)**
[image: my contenteditable]

[This 2016 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301159/13991219) says that Google Docs uses `<iframe>` to display the background color, but I inspected the elements in my latest docs and I didn't find any iframes/spans specifically for a highlighted background color.(Perhaps they're using a different method?) I also noticed that this is possible in other scenarios: when you prompt a dialog/click on the inspect console, the existing selected text will not be lost and its background changes to a color similar to what Google Docs uses:
[image: prompt effect]

Is it possible to keep an "in-the-background-gray-selection" while inputting in another panel? If not, why could the selection be kept when inputting into a dialog? I feel like the answer is obvious but I just missed an important attribute.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592627/using-multiple-carets-in-single-or-multiple-textareas-and-textboxes

Comment: It's important to mention that Google Doc is not just a simple textarea. It's essentially a "textarea" which has been completely coded from the ground up. They are able to make whatever rules they want because they aren't bound by the default rules of the basic html elements. I haven't looked into this but it seems like you'd most likely have to do some crazy stuff to get the desired effect.

Comment: @a.mola Thanks for the link - I'm not really trying to include code here, so ACE will probably not work for me. I also experimented with other editors such as TinyMCE and CKEditor but it turns out that they would have me install a bunch of plugins for some features to work and their interface is incompatible with the rest of my page -- so then I decided to build my own.